# No se capturan los errores personalizados de sql server en java

Tags: java, sql-server

tengo un sp en SQL Server para inserción de datos, las instrucciones están dentro de un bloque try-catch y tengo un mensaje de error personalizado usando la instrucción **THROW**.

El asunto es que cuando se dispara este error en la base de datos mi aplicación Java no lo captura en el bloque catch, es mas, la aplicación nunca captura el error.

**Definición bloque CATCH SP**

```
BEGIN CATCH
    
    DECLARE @codigo INT = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, last_used_value) FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'SQ_cliente_codigo')
    DECLARE @opcionmensage VARCHAR(25)

    IF @tipocliente = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @opcionmensage = 'Personas.'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @opcionmensage = 'Empresas.'
        END

    IF (SELECT ERROR_NUMBER()) = 547 AND (SELECT ERROR_STATE()) = 0
        BEGIN

            EXEC ('ALTER SEQUENCE SQ_cliente_codigo
            RESTART WITH '+@codigo)

            DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(2048) = 'El documento: ' + @documento + ', no existe en Padrón ' + @opcionmensage;
            THROW 50001, @msg, 1;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN;
            THROW;
        END

END CATCH
GO
```

**Bloque de código java**

```
public boolean InsertarDatos(AdmDatosCliente adc) {
        Alert mensaje;

        try {
            // Conexion a la base de datos.
            Connection conn = con.getConnection();

            // Consulta a la base de datos.
            CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call sp_AdmDatosCliente_insertarDatos(?,?,?,?)}");

            // Parametros de consulta.
            cs.setInt(1, adc.getId_tipocliente()); // id_tipo_cliente.
            cs.setString(2, adc.getDocumento()); // documento.
            cs.setInt(3, adc.getId_estatus()); // id_estatus.
            cs.setString(4, adc.getAlias()); // alias.
            
            // Ejecutar Query
            cs.execute();
            
            System.out.println(rs = cs.getResultSet());
            
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("codigo"));
            }

            conn.close();

            return true;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            
            mensaje = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            mensaje.setTitle("Error");
            mensaje.setHeaderText(null);
            mensaje.setContentText(e.getMessage());
            mensaje.showAndWait();

            return false;
        }
    }
```

He revisado la documentación de Microsoft y no encuentro nada, agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor agrega el mensaje de error que tienes o algo para que nos guie

Comment: @DavElsanto esto no genera ningún error. Cuando ocurre un error en el SP este lo captura y hace la salida correctamente, sin embargo es la aplicación que nunca la dispara.

Comment: trata de asignar el error a una variable de salida

Comment: Bueno, ya lo solucione, al parecer el problema estaba en el bloque try, en el cual estaba implementado un SQL dinámico y esto por algún motivo cuando se disparaba el error no lo pasaba a la aplicación, sustituí todo ese bloque por un query más eficiente y se solucionó.